# Print book Titles with corresponding images covers

Tags: php, html, css

The file data is a list of book titles, and links to their cover images (hosted on Wikipedia). novels.txt and covers.txt.
Read in both files, and create a table

Each row should include the title of the book on the left, and an embedded image tag.

Here's my code.

```
//load file
$covers = file("covers.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$novels = file("novels.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

//print table header
print "<table
        <tr>
            <th>Book</th>
            <th>Cover</th>";
            
foreach($novels as $i=>$novel){
    print "<tr>
            <td>$novel</td>
            <td>$covers[$i]</td>
            </tr>";
"</table>";
```

}

It is printing out the title of the book with the corresponding URL instead of the image. How do i get it to print out the image?

Comment: try: `<td><img src='{$covers[$i]}' alt='cover'></td>`.

Comment: Some info on `<img>` elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img